# Ungroup a dictionary

Tags: kdb

Suppose the parent vector `p` is defined as list where each element is a pointer to the position index of the parent of the given item in the same vector.
Then children of each parent can be found as:

```
q) c:group p:0N 0 1 0 2
 | ,0
0| 1 3
1| ,2
2| ,4
```

If `c` is given, what is the efficient way to flatten children dictionary `c` back to the parent vector `p`?

Obviously `ungroup` does not work on dictionaries directly:

```
q) ungroup c
'type
```

But we can ungroup tables:

```
q) {@[;`k] `v xasc ungroup ([]k:key x;v:value x)} c
0N 0 1 0 2
```

Is there more efficient solution how to get `p` given `c` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
 q) @[raze c;value c;:;key c] 
 q) 0N 0 1 0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no native q command for the type of ungroup you're looking for.
One option that may be useful is the following function:

```
invgroup:{key[x]@[raze x;value x;:;til count x]}
```

Effectively what this does is, returns the values of the group dictionary as a single list (raze x), indexes into this list at each set of associated indices (value x) and assigns these the correct index from the original list.
Then we use these indices to index into the distinct values of the original list (key x) to pull out the original list

```
p ~ invgroup group p:0N 0 1 0 2
1b
```